# Is the Goel HaDam (Blood Avenger) obligated to pursue blood vengeance?

Tags: halacha, murder, city-of-refuge

During times when the Torah is the law of the land, if a Jew commits accidental murder against another Jew, he must [flee](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43947/can-the-goel-hadam-kill-the-inadvertent-killer-if-he-lives-in-any-refuge-city) to a Ir Miklat (City of Refuge) or else be subject to revenge killing by the Goel HaDam (Blood Avenger).

Is the Goel HaDam *obligated* to make a reasonable effort to kill the accidental murderer before he arrives in (or if he leaves) the Ir Miklat, or it is he simply *allowed* to do so if he wishes? For example, would it be a sin for him to forgive the killer or to decide not to attack despite the opportunity? Is it a mitzvah for the Goel HaDam to complete the act of revenge and/or make reasonable efforts to do so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the matter of a Tannaic dispute recorded in the Mishna ([Makkot 2:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h45.htm)), [Makkot (11a)](http://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.11a?lang=bi):

> רוצח שיצא חוץ לתחום, ומצאו גואל הדם--רבי יוסי הגלילי אומר, מצוה ביד גואל הדם, ורשות ביד כל אדם; רבי עקיבה אומר, רשות ביד גואל הדם, וכל אדם אין חייבין עליו.
>
> A murderer who left the bounds [of the city of refuge] R. Jose the Galilean says: it is a mitsvah for the *goel hadam* [to kill him] and permitted for everyone else. R. Akiva says: It is permissible [only] for the *goel hadam*, but anyone else would not be liable [for killing him].

Rambam ([Hilkhot Rotseah 5:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/b505.htm)) rules in accordance with Rabbi Akiva that it is merely permissible for the *goel hadam* to kill him; not an obligation:

> רוצח בשגגה שהרגו גואל הדם חוץ לתחום עיר מקלטו--פטור..אחד ההורגו בדרך קודם שייכנס לעיר מקלטו... נכנס לעיר מקלטו, ויצא חוץ לתחומה בזדון--הרי זה התיר עצמו למיתה, ורשות לגואל הדם להורגו
>
> If a *goel hadam* killed one who killed inadvertently outside of the bounds of the city, he is exempt...Whether he killed him on the way before he entered the city of refuge...[or] if he entered the city of refuge, and deliberately left its boundaries--he has made it permissible to kill him, and it is permissible to the *goel hadam* to kill him.

Comment: What about the Goel HaDam of a Meizid murderer?

Comment: @DoubleAA does that exist? I thought a Goel HaDam was a special exception that only exists for a *shogeg* murder

Comment: @alicht אוֹ בְאֵיבָה הִכָּהוּ בְיָדוֹ, וַיָּמֹת--מוֹת-יוּמַת הַמַּכֶּה, רֹצֵחַ הוּא:  גֹּאֵל הַדָּם, יָמִית אֶת-הָרֹצֵחַ--בְּפִגְעוֹ-בוֹ Maybe you shouldn't be asking about female nazir :P

Comment: @DoubleAA haha true! Should put down my *Makkos* and pick up a *Chumash* :)

Comment: @DoubleAA question: but if we say that a *goel hadam* (Reuven) can kill the intentional murderer (Shimon)- can't a *karov* from Shimon's  now be a *goel hadam* and try and kill Reuven? (and this would back and forth 100x with everyone avenging everyone's death)

Comment: @alicht no. Shimon was executed not murdered

Comment: @DoubleAA those phrases sound very similar- but essentially what you’re saying is that the if *goel hadam* kills that’s it, it’s over- right?

Comment: @alicht I think so

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds like a sound svara to me- because if it’s the way I suggested, then you could say the family of someone killed by the Sanhedrin could be a goel hadam to the Sanhedrin which is... absurd